# Lectura de saltos de linea wordpress

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, wordpress-theme

Llevo varios días intentando buscar una solución , en php es una chorrada y he sabido solucionarlo , pero a la hora de acoplarlo a mi página de wordpress imposible.

El problema es el siguiente quiero crear por cada linea obtenida de la base de datos una lista, `<li>EJEMPLO</li>`
    El tema es que intento encontrar cuando es un `"\n" o "<br />"` y nunca lo encuentra o bien porque omite caracteres.
En la base de datos los datos son almacenados con un textarea que respeta los saltos de linea.

A continuacion dejo el codigo.

```
 for($i=0;$i<strlen(nl2br($row['starter']));$i++){
        if($row['starter'][$i]=="\n"){
            echo "<li>";
         }else{
            if(ctype_upper($resul[0][$i])){
                echo $row['starter'][$i];
            }else{
                echo $row['starter'][$i];
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Te aconsejo usar la funcion ***nl2br*** al insertar en la base de datos. O sea, guardar el texto con el `<br>`.

Pero por lo pronto esto debería funcionar.

`$texto = str_replace("<br />","<br>",$row['starter']);`

`$texto = str_replace("\n","<br>",$texto);`

`$texto = explode("<br>",$texto);`

`echo '<ul>'`;

`foreach($texto as $item){
       echo '<li>'.$item.'</li>';
   }`

`echo '</ul>';`